# UINavigationController animation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, popviewcontroller

I have a tabBar app with two tabs. Each tab has its own navigationController implemented this way:

```
FirstViewController *firstController = [[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *firstNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:firstController];

SecondViewController *secondController = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *secondNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:secondController];

tabBar.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:firstNavController, secondNavController, nil];
```

When I want to push a view into one tab I use this:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:activityController animated:YES];
```

And when I am on a pushed view and I want to pop the view I use:

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

The push animation works great but in the pop animation only the top bar (the NavigationController) gets animated and the view disappears without the animation. What can be wrong?

Comment: Are you calling this from the main thread?

Comment: Yes, I don't know what can I do to make it work

Answer (score 0):

Try using `[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];`

Instead of `[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];`
 and tell me if this works. Remember for netsted navigation controllers.

Comment: No I have already tried that without any success. Only the top navigationController bar get animated, not the view...

Comment: come to chat in iphone ipad room

Comment: I have arc enabled, so there is no dealloc method